# RecursionError en mis clases de modelo django

Tags: python, string, django-models, class

Hola <3 cuando ejecuto mi servidor django me sale este error en mis clases de modelo no me muestra mis metodos str y me da el error recursionerror y eh tratado de reducir el codigo y aun no entiendo bien que pasa (soy algo nueva en esto de la programacion y estoy aprendiendo) quisiera que me muestre bien mis strings, omito la clase domicilio porque es la unica que funciona bien y me muestra bien mi str

Nota: Realmente quiero aprender, y mas aprender de mis errores <3

```
class Persona(models.Model):
   dni = models.CharField(max_length=8, primary_key=True)
   apellido_materno = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   apellido_paterno = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   nombres = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField()
   sexos = [
       ('F', 'Femenino'),
       ('M', 'Masculino')
   ]
   sexo = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=sexos, default='F')
   domicilio = models.ForeignKey(Domicilio, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   def nombreCompleto(self):
       formato_nombre = "{0} {1}, {2}"
       return formato_nombre.format(self.apellido_paterno, self.apellido_materno, self.nombres)

   def __str__(self):
       return f'{self.dni}: {self.nombreCompleto}, {self.sexo}, {self.fecha_nacimiento}'


class Ocupacion(models.Model):
   estatus = [
       ('No', 'Soltero'),
       ('Si', 'Casado'),
   ]
   casado = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=estatus, default='No')

   ocupaciones = [
       ('Si', 'Si Trabajo'),
       ('No', 'No Trabajo'),
   ]
   trabajo = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=ocupaciones, default='Si')
   sociales = models.CharField(max_length=255)

   def __str__(self):
       if self.Persona.sexo == "F":
           letrasexo = "a"
       else:
           letrasexo = "o"
       return f'Estado Casad{letrasexo}: {self.casado}, Trabaja: {self.trabajo},Red Social: {self.sociales}'


class Registro(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   persona = models.ForeignKey(Persona, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   info_persona = models.ForeignKey(Ocupacion, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   fecha_registro = models.DateField(auto_created=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return f'ID: {self.id} Contacto: {self.persona} Fecha Registro: {self.fecha_registro}'

Gracias por su ayuda <3
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Si, Gracias , cuando agrege mi metodo str y ejecute el servidor me sale el recursionerror ej django, y trate de investigar y hacer mas corto mi codigo, mi pregunta en especifico es porque me esta pasando esto, si omiti algo soy algo nueva en esto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si se agrega el decorador **@property** en la clase **Persona** se evita el error:

```
@property
def nombreCompleto(self):
    formato_nombre = "{0} {1}, {2}"
    return formato_nombre.format(self.apellido_paterno, self.apellido_materno, self.nombres)
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo parecido en la documentación de django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#model-methods

Comment: Muchas Gracias <3